# copy image from one server to another by maintaining quality

Tags: php, ftp

hey i am doing this first time. actually i have uploaded one image on my server now i want to make the copy of all that images on my another server by maintaining its quality. code is working and image is copied from another server but the image is messed up totaly
i have tried with

```
ftp_nb_put() 
ftp_nb_fput()
ftp_put() 
ftp_fput
```

i am getting the same response by each of this function. can you tell me any other alternate option for me. i want to transfer not only image a .txt file doc file ,.xls file is also possible.
Thanks in advance
code

```
<?php

$conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.domain.com');           
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'pass');

$file = 'http://myserver.com/upload/g.jpg';
$remote_file = 'g.jpg';
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

the image is changed and it look like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your image is in jpg format, no ftp based command should have an effect on it one way or another.  Presumably, your quality loss is occurring during your actual storage routine, either after you have retrieved the image file through ftp or when you first uploaded the file to the original server.  Can we see some code?

Comment: actually i have uploaded image on my server and it successfully done with its original quality but now as a backup i want to copy all that images to my  another server . its a simple image uploading code. here above i have mentioned my copy image code

Comment: Well I can tell you for sure that the ftp commands will not decrease the quality of your image; that is definitely occurring somewhere else.

Can you link to the before and after images?

Comment: Also, when you say that the quality is lost, do you mean that the image becomes more compressed, or that it is literally corrupted and impossible to view?

Comment: image is totaly messed up.no i haven't link it before and after

Comment: <?php

$conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.domain.com');   
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'pass');

$file = 'http://myserver.com/upload/g.jpg';
$remote_file = 'g.jpg';
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>              here is a simple code you can directly copy/paste it and check this

Comment: i am very confused about it

Comment: Is that actually how you have it pointing to the file on your server?  Have you tried a relative path?

Comment: Also, have you tried
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)

Comment: Try switching to FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII

Comment: its really work ,thanks bro its work like charm. all the images are copied with same quality. thanks again bro,